# An odd issue with copy module and Sublime Text2

Tags: python, copy, sublimetext2

Something strange is happening. I am getting an error when running this code in *Sublime Text 2* while the code is valid elsewhere.

```
import copy

s = 'string'
cs = copy.copy(s)
print s == cs
```

I got the `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`

Also, `copy.deepcopy()` throws an error `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'deepcopy'` while running inside of ST2.

I am aware this is the ST2 specific problem, but maybe some of you know whether this can be solved?

Comment: Check python version in ST2: `import sys;print sys.version`

Comment: You use copy when you want to make a copy of a structure. However, it will not make a copy of something that is interned. This includes integers less than 256, True, False, None, short strings like a. , you should never use it unless you're sure you won't be messed up by interning.

Comment: `2.7.3 |EPD_free 7.3-2 (32-bit)` how does it help me?

Comment: Kobi, I am not exactly sure what do you mean by interning but the code works inside of the Shell, eclipse and so on, so I can't see why ST2 would throw an error.

Comment: try changing your import to this `from copy import copy`

Comment: I tried this, `ImportError: cannot import name copy`.

Comment: that seems to be the root of the problem, because it works in the interpreter

Comment: Works fine for me in Sublimetext2(2.0.2, Build 2221)

Comment: Have you created your own **copy.py** file somewhere in the module search path?
Try: `print copy.__file__`

Comment: I did actually. Thanks! Renaming the file however, changed the error to (this error also pops up when I run `print copy.__file__`) `ImportError: cannot import name copy`.

Comment: @nutship Get rid of the `copy.pyc` file too.

Comment: Wow, it did the trick! Awesome. Please provide an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you've masked the built-in `copy` module my adding your own `copy` module somewhere in the [module search path](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path) used by [sublimetext2](/questions/tagged/sublimetext2).

To fix that rename your `copy.py` file to something else and also delete the `copy.pyc` file.

The location of the file can be found using `__file__` attribute of the module object.

```
import copy
print copy.__file__
```

In future please don't name your modules or packages same as python built-in modules, otherwise you'll face same issues.